# shellscript deployments feedback/schedule

Tags: deployment, jenkins, web-deployment

We have an enterprise web application which is deployed on s3/cloudfront. Deployments are mostly done at night for less impact to users (local application used mostly in the day).

Current deployment process is to execute a shellscript on server which uses some credentials stored as system env variables. Shell script internally uses grunt task for build and deploy to s3.

Problems

1. When we run shellscript and if there occured some problems, there is no feedback to one who is doing deployment if he is not looking at the console. Whats the easiest way to implement a feedback system like email if deployment fails.
2. If we can implement a feedback system, can we do unattended scheduled builds using some tools like jenkins or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could create a rake task which executes your deployment script using popen (http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO.popen) and then send you the results of the command execution (and returnstatus)
2. This way you could automate the rake task execution via cron or whenever gem (if available) or something alternative like clockwork gem (if you're on a PaaS f.e.)